# Select Field not Updating Options when Looping it

Tags: python, html, selenium, select

I'm working on a automation for a horrible website for a governamental agency in Peru, and since the website is slow and it takes a while to load all options of the select fields in the website, I decied to loop that field until the option appears before moving to the next steps, however, ven after the site updates, my code doesn't seem to get the updated options. What I have is the following:

```
waitTime = True
while waitTime == True:
    selectField = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, timeWait).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, elemXPathSelect))))
    time.sleep(pageLoadingTime)
    selectFieldOptions = [o.text for o in selectField.options]
    if (len(selectFieldOptions) >= 2):
        waitTime = False
```

This keeps returning to me only 1 option, which is the default before the other ones are loaded, and even after the site loads the other options, my code gets stuck on this loop because it always returns 1 option only.

The website code is structured like this:

```
<select _ngcontent-uaw-c2="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"><!----> 
    <option _ngcontent-uaw-c2="" value="202102" class="ng-star-inserted">202102</option>
    <option _ngcontent-uaw-c2="" value="202103" class="ng-star-inserted">202103</option>
    <option _ngcontent-uaw-c2="" value="202104" class="ng-star-inserted">202104</option>
    <option _ngcontent-uaw-c2="" value="202105" class="ng-star-inserted">202105</option>
    <option _ngcontent-uaw-c2="" value="202106" class="ng-star-inserted">202106</option>
    <option _ngcontent-uaw-c2="" value="202107" class="ng-star-inserted">202107</option>
    <option _ngcontent-uaw-c2="" value="202108" class="ng-star-inserted">202108</option>
    <option _ngcontent-uaw-c2="" value="202109" class="ng-star-inserted">202109</option>
    <option _ngcontent-uaw-c2="" value="202110" class="ng-star-inserted">202110</option>
    <option _ngcontent-uaw-c2="" value="202111" class="ng-star-inserted">202111</option>
    <option _ngcontent-uaw-c2="" value="202112" class="ng-star-inserted">202112</option>
    <option _ngcontent-uaw-c2="" value="202201" class="ng-star-inserted">202201</option>
    <option _ngcontent-uaw-c2="" value="202202" class="ng-star-inserted">202202</option>
</select>
```

If anybody has any ideas, I'd sure appreciate it!

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I explained it enough... There is a selection field that is dynamically populated, it starts with just 1 option, and after a few seconds it changes to multiple options. What I do is keep selecting the web element as a variable and checking how many options it has. At first it only has 1 cause the field has only 1 option, after a few seconds the field gets new options added to it dynamically, so I loop the field to check for when it has 2 or more options, however, even after the field has more than 1 option, my code returns that select field with only one option.

Comment: _returning to me only 1 option_: Which option does it returns? What is the value of _`timeWait`_? How is _`elemXPathSelect`_ defined?

Comment: Sorry about that, timeWait is set to 30 Seconds and elemXPathSelect is a string that contain the full XPath of the Select Element ("/html/body/app-root/app-modules/div/app-registro-operaciones/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/app-operacion/div/form/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/rr-combo-catalogo/select") I'm trying to loop... The timeWait isnt very usefull on this case as I mentioned because the button shows up in the page ready to use with 1 option, than after a few seconds it gets the new options.

The Default one option for the Field is "- TODOS -"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding a time.sleep(2) before going to the Select element, which means it will be ready with all options loaded and the code will work... I still don't understand why the loop is failing with the sleep since the select element changes and the code doesnt seem to take that into consideration.